# Checking if the array has duplicates apart from one element Javascript Dice

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi im struggling to impliment a function to simply check if an array has all the same numbers apart from one.
I have tried a few methods now and i feel like im getting nowhere.
The reason for this is for a dice game the user can select a number of dices and then roll and score bonus points for duplicate numbers and other sequences ect..

I thought it would be simple to check if the array had all duplciates apart from one element in the array but i cant get it to work.
I was thinking of something like check the elements in the aray and see if the all the elements are the same value apart from one by using something with the array.length-1.
Examples dice values which would be true:

```
[1,2,2,2] or [4,4,2,4] (for 4 dice) //true
[1,1,6] (for 3 dice )//true
```

I tried something like this :

```
function countDuplicate(array){
  var count=0;
  var sorted_array=array.sort();
  for (let i=1;i<sorted_array.length;i++)
  {
    if (sorted_array[i] ==sorted_array[i+1]){
        count+=count;}
  }
  if (count===sorted_array.length-1){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

but it doesnt seem to work.
Hope this is enough sorry im new to javascript and stackoverflow.

Comment: What would be some examples of false cases? Is [2, 2, 4, 4] true or false? Is [1, 2, 3, 4, 4] true or false? Is [1, 2] true or false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to implement this is to build an array of counts of each of the values in the array. This list can then be checked to ensure its length is 2 and the minimum count is 1:

```js
const countDuplicate = (array) => {
  let counts = Object.values(array.reduce((c, v) =>
    (c[v] = (c[v] || 0) + 1, c), {}));
  return counts.length == 2 && Math.min(...counts) == 1
}

console.log(countDuplicate([1,2,2,2]));
console.log(countDuplicate([4,4,2,4]));
console.log(countDuplicate([1,1,6]));
console.log(countDuplicate([2,2,4,4]));
console.log(countDuplicate([1,2]));
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're simply just wanting to check if all values are the same except for one in array you can just use this.

```
function oneMultiple(array) {
  const set = new Set(array)

  return set.size === 2
}
```

Comment: It's unclear if this would satisfy OP's needs. I.e. [2, 2, 4, 4] would return true, but this is not all duplicate except 1.

Comment: thanks you for the help sorry i forgot to mention [2,2,4,4] should return false . I noticed when i rolled [5,5,2,2] it returns true it rolls true for [5,5,5,2] which is great!. Is there an easy fix for the [2,2,4,4] problem ?

Answer (score 0):

This is using `Set` and it compares the length of original array and array of removed duplicates:

```js
const hasDuplicates = (arr = []) => {
  const noDuplicates = [...new Set(arr)];

  return arr.length !== noDuplicates.length;
};

console.log(hasDuplicates([1,2,3]));
console.log(hasDuplicates([1,2,3,1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to simply use one values **USE THIS**

```
function oneMultiple(array) {
  const set = new Set(array)

  return set.size === 2
}
```